# Windows - PHPDocs unable to install through Pear

Tags: php, wamp, pear

When running the two commands to install phpdocs:

> pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org pear install
>
> phpdoc/phpDocumentor

I get this error below saying I am unable to unpack a tgz file below.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear>pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
            
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear>pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
downloading phpDocumentor-2.8.2.tgz ...
Starting to download phpDocumentor-2.8.2.tgz (16,246,834 bytes)
            ................................................................................
            ................................................................................
            ................................................................................
..........................done: 16,246,834 bytes
ERROR: unable to unpack C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download\p
            hpDocumentor-2.8.2.tgz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the PEAR installer was unable to uncompress the downloaded .tgz for some reason, perhaps the zlib extension wasn't compiled in, for example.

As a work-around, you can specify that PEAR should request the uncompressed package file instead:

```
pear install --nocompress phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

Comment: not working no. although tarball is uncompressed fine. Is there a way to install uncompressed package?

Comment: Yes. This is how to do it "by hand": You need to extract the package to a temporary directory, call it uncompressedpackagedir if you want. In uncompressedpackagedir you'll see a package.xml which you will need to copy or move into the newly created directory named for the package you extracted. In the case of phpDocumentor v2.8.2 it will be named phpDocumentor-2.8.2.  cd into that directory and do "$ sudo pear installl package.xml".

Answer (score 10):

Faced the same problem, turns out package for 2.8.2 has issues, because 
`pear install phpdoc/PhpDocumentor-2.8.1` worked just fine

Comment: This info helped me a great deal. I tried to figure out what the probem with my pear installation is when only the phpdoc package has an issue really

Comment: I think there may be something wrong with your setup as I was able to install 2.8.2 without issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried @kguest answer ->

```
  pear install --nocompress phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

with no luck. So I tried "upgrading"

```
 pear upgrade C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download\phpDocumentor-2.8.2.tar
```

Again, with no luck. Then I build my own solution:

1) Extract the files from the PEAR temp directory:

```
  C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download\phpDocumentor-2.8.2.tar
```

2) Repack the recently extracted files as TAR (I used 7zip).

3) Reattempt the upgrade but from the newly created TAR:

```
  C:\temp\phpDocumentor.tar
```

And only THEN it worked.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for **phpDocumentor 2.8.5** was

1. Download the tarball archive from
   https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases
2. Uncompress the archive **phpDocumentor-2.8.5.tgz** manulay (e.g. with 7zip) You will get the **phpDocumentor-2.8.5.tar**, uncompress it too and you will get the folder **phpDocumentor-2.8.5** and the file **package.xml**
3. Edit the archive **package.xml** and change the text **template:init** to **template_init** (line 2036) in fact it is a path (Info source: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1608)
4. Compress the folder **phpDocumentor-2.8.5** and the file **package.xml** (e.g. **phpdoc285.tar**)
5. Install the archive **phpdoc285.tar**

   pear install --nocompress phpdoc285.tar

Comment: I now get the error message:
pear install "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download\phpDocumentor-2.8.5.tar"
ERROR: file C:\xampp\php\tmp\tmp7F1F.tmp\phpDocumentor-2.8.5\ansible\roles\phpdocumentor.environment\handlers\main.yml does not exist

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of trying other people's solutions I've finally got it working phpDocumentor 2.9.0

You can download it from:

https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases

then use pear install "filepath\phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz"

Answer (score -1):

This issue is especially on windows os, to avoid the error :

> ERROR: unable to unpack ...

install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) before you launch the phpdoc command