# How to install phpDocumentor with pear on cygwin

Tags: windows, cmd, installation, command, cygwin

I saw that : [Installing phpDocumentor using PEAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518713/installing-phpdocumentor-using-pear) (2013)
AND I used the official doc : https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/getting-started/installing.html
AND I try this issue : https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/issues/2113

**From Doc :**

When i try :

```sh
1 | pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
2 | pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

The result :

```sh
1 | Channel "pear.phpdoc.org" is already initialized
2 | No releases available for package "pear.phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor"
2 | install failed
```

**From Issue :**

Let's try issue :

```sh
1 | wget https://pear.phpdoc.org/channel.xml
2 | pear channel-update ./channel.xml
3 | pear install http://pear.phpdoc.org/get/phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz
```

The result :

```sh
1 | 200 OK
1 | « channel.xml.1 » saved
2 | Update of Channel "pear.phpdoc.org" succeeded
3 | phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz
3 | Could not download from "http://pear.phpdoc.org/get/phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz" (File
3 | http://pear.phpdoc.org:80/get/phpDocumentor-2.9.0.tgz not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent 3 3 | Redirect))
3 | Invalid or missing remote package file
3 | install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution here : [Windows - PHPDocs unable to install through Pear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358699/windows-phpdocs-unable-to-install-through-pear)

So we need to extract the package *to a temporary directory, call it uncompressedpackagedir if you want. In uncompressedpackagedir you'll see a package.xml which you will need to copy or move into the newly created directory named for the package you extracted. In the case of phpDocumentor v2.8.2 it will be named phpDocumentor-2.8.2. cd into that directory and do "$ sudo pear installl package.xml*

But when i run phpdoc --version i get an error (require_once Fatal error: failing to open stream, saying no such file or directory ... Bootstrap.php)

so I give up pear and i use .phar installation as described at documentation on github : https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor#using-the-phar